# GNU watch without erasing previous outputs

Tags: command-line, watch-command

[gnu `watch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix)) is a very useful tool for inspecting a program output: It executes the program and shows the output full-screen every 2 seconds.

Sometimes, I don't want the previous output to be erased, but rather be printed line by line with a time stamp. For that, I use bash scripts like:

```
while true; 
    do echo -n "`date`   "; 
    ssh ubuntu@server -o ConnectTimeout=1 "uptime" ; 
    sleep 1; 
done
```

Is there a [`watch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix))-like tool that can run a command and display its output with a timestamp in a line without erasing previous output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say you've found it in simple loops but you could do a number of things from here:

### Write a function to handle that for you

```bash
function uberwatch {
    # call: uberwatch <interval> <command>
    while true; do
        "${@:2}";
        sleep $1;
    done
}
```

You could lodge that somewhere around your `~/.bashrc`.

### Log the output to file but keep viewing with `watch`

```bash
watch "command | tee -a watchlog.log"
```

You'd still only see the latest run-through but you could dig through a historical log if you needed to.

Comment: uberwatch's syntax does not parse. `syntax error near unexpected token done`

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii Thanks, there were a few errors. Have fixed.

Comment: Is there a modification to uberwatch that supports multiple commands? For example `uberwatch 2 "date; ls"
bash: date; ls: command not found`

Comment: On the other hand, `while true; do date; ls; sleep 2; done` works.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii Since `${@:2}` is encapsulated with double quotes, your command is run like so: `while true; do "date; ls"; sleep 2; done` which gives the same error you get. If you want to run more than 1 command, I'd recommend putting those inside a separate script, and call that script with the `uberwatch` function. Such as: `uberwatch 2 /path/to/the/custom/script`

Answer (score 1):

while true; do date >> /vat/tmp/watch.log; sleep 600; ls -l filename >> /var/tmp/watch.log; done

I like the while loop mentioned by Artem above but was looking to store the data in a file so i can analyze it when i got back, hence added redirects to a file. In my case watching file every 10mins and ls -l for file size

-Jay

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail please? What does this do that the other answer doesn’t? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, i should have mentioned that i was look for same function but also save the output to a file so i can walk away and analyze the data when i got back. Hence added redirects to store output for each iteration

Comment: can you edit your answer to say that? Might help other people - thanks!